# APEX Tabular Form with [row selector]: How to set value of column in selected rows on submit

Tags: oracle-apex, tabular-form

I have a tabular form that displays all requests submitted for processing. Submitters have the opportunity to cancel requests at any time. I would like this to be accomplished by simply checking the row selector checkbox of the row(s) that should be cancelled and clicking submit.

Ok... What I am trying to create is a tabular form that, when the [row selector] checkbox is checked and the form is submitted, the value in the 'Status' column of the row is set as 'Cancelled'.

Since the [row selector] checkboxes exist, my guess is there is probably a built in process of some sort that identifies the selected rows and runs an action on the selected rows.

Is there a way to tap into this functionality and take the extra step to set the value of the 'Status' column of the row to 'Cancelled'?

Answer (score 3):

Read my comment on Tom's answer. Example code of process:

```
declare 
  l_map apex_application_global.vc_map;
  l_region_id number;
begin
  if :APEX$ROW_SELECTOR = 'X' then
    select t.region_id
     into l_region_id
     from APEX_040100.APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_RPT t
     where t.application_id = :APP_ID
       and t.page_id = :APP_PAGE_ID
       and t.source_type = 'Tabular Form';

    l_map := apex_040100.wwv_flow_tabular_form.get_row_values(
      p_tabular_form_region_id => l_region_id,
      p_row_num => :APEX$ROW_NUM
    );

    update my_table
     set status = 'Cancelled'
     where id = l_map('ID');
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Very interesting. I didn't know about that. However, it isn't really a documented feature, is it?

Comment: New items (APEX$ROW_SELECTOR,... etc.) documented feature http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/concept_sub.htm#HTMDB28714. wwv_flow_tabular_form.get_row_values - no, i can't found in documentation.

Comment: The link is expired please use this new link https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_sub.htm#CHDGJFII

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the added row selector will be stored in the `apex_application.g_f01` array (more info on those arrays, [see the apex api doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/apex_app.htm#CHDDADIE)). Verify this by looking at your html output of your page. After your tabular form html you can find the input to array mapping (i used a tabular form based on the `EMP` table):

```
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Select Row" id="fhdr_001" />
<input type="hidden" name="fmap" value="EMPNO" id="fmap_002" />
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Empno" id="fhdr_002" />
<input type="hidden" name="fmap" value="ENAME" id="fmap_003" />
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Ename" id="fhdr_003" />
<input type="hidden" name="fmap" value="JOB" id="fmap_004" />
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Job" id="fhdr_004" />
<input type="hidden" name="fmap" value="MGR" id="fmap_005" />
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Mgr" id="fhdr_005" />
<input type="hidden" name="fmap" value="HIREDATE" id="fmap_006" />
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Hiredate" id="fhdr_006" />
<input type="hidden" name="fmap" value="DEPTNO" id="fmap_007" />
<input type="hidden" name="fhdr" value="Deptno" id="fhdr_007" />
```

You will need the row selector (array f01), and any other value you think you'll need.
For example, i used array 3: `ENAME`.

```
DECLARE
   v_rowno NUMBER;
BEGIN
   for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count
   loop
      v_rowno := apex_application.g_f01(i);
      apex_debug_message.log_message('row# selected: '||v_rowno);
      apex_debug_message.log_message('Employee: '||apex_application.g_f03(v_rowno));
   end loop;
END;
```

On my tabular form, i went to page 2 and selected 2 employees.
[image: selected employees]

This outputs in my debug to:

```
row# selected: 2
Employee: ADAMS
row# selected: 3
Employee: JAMES
```

Take note that the row selector value is the rownumber for the current page of the report.

If you need to update a status, you'll need to reference an array which holds the ID for a record. This way you'll be able to perform an `UPDATE` on those records.

Comment: APEX 4.1 has new features. You can associate your process with tabular form, set his scope "For created and modified rows". This process will execute for each modified row. So you can use APEX$ROW_SELECTOR variable to test if row selector was checked (return X if checked and null if not). Also it has variables APEX$ROW_NUM and APEX$ROW_STATUS to get rownum and status of current row. Also i use apex_040100.wwv_flow_tabular_form.get_row_values function to get associative array of row values indexed by column names. So you can get column values without ugly "apex_application.g_fXX" construction.